Using an external function to fetch data in NextJS
I'm trying to limit repeated code by moving the code that fetches data to an external file.
The fetchUserInfo I'm using uses the useEffect, useState hooks and as such needs to be a "use client" component.
For some reason when I try to import an external function that has "use client" react refuses to recognise the fuction and spits out:
Error: (0 , fetchUserInfo__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_.default) is not a function.
Thanks in advance for any response.
My folder structure:

Component code:
import fetchUserInfo from "./fetchUserInfo"


const VideoTestimonial = ({ channelLink }) => {
    fetchUserInfo(channelLink)
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>

    )
}

export default VideoTestimonial

Function code:
"use client"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
const API_KEY = "INSERT_KEY"

export default function fetchUserInfo(channelLink) {
    const channelId = channelLink;

    const API_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=${channelId}&key=${API_KEY}`
    const PIC_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id=${channelId}&fields=items%2Fsnippet%2Fthumbnails&key=${API_KEY}`
    const USERNAME_URL = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id=${channelId}&key=${API_KEY}`

    const [username, setUsername] = useState("loading")
    const [profileImage, setprofileImage] = useState("")
    const [subCount, setSubCount] = useState("loading")

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(API_URL)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => { setSubCount(Number(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount).toLocaleString("de-DE")) })
            .catch((error) => {
            });

        fetch(PIC_URL)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => { setprofileImage(data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url) })
            .catch((error) => {
            });

        fetch(USERNAME_URL)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => { setUsername(data.items[0].brandingSettings.channel.title) })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        {
            username: username,
            profileImage: profileImage,
            subCount: subCount
        }
    )
}

I expected the function to be imported without issues.

React Hooks Must be used in a react functional component and cannot be used in standalone function line your doing in fetchUserInfo
Additionally you should not be using useState and useEffect in a function that's meant to be a utility function
you can move fetching logic directly inside your component
